# Can't run Safari 10.1 OS X El Capitan in full screen with selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

I try to run Safari in full screen with self.driver.maximize_window(),but the browser is not in the full screen even the self.driver.maximize_window() is executed. Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a known defect for apple, they are working on fixing it, i do not have the link handy, but you can look it up on the list of apple webdriver bugs, the maximize does not work in safari nor in safari technology preview.